# Por que um retorno com status code 200 retorna antes um 204?

Tags: http-status

Tenho reparado que toda resposta de **Sucesso (200)** há também uma resposta **Sem Conteúdo (204)**.

Fiquei curioso e fui pesquisar na [MDN sobre o status 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200), a única coisa que diz que os resultados de sucesso de um `PUT` e um `DELETE` devem retornar um `204`. Tenho feito uma requisição `GET` e após isso tenho uma *request* com o verbo `OPTIONS` retornando um status `204`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque um retorno com status code 200 retorna também um 204 com o verbo `OPTIONS`?

Comment: "[...] Por exemplo, um código de status 204 é comumente usado com interfaces de edição de documentos correspondentes a uma ação "salvar", de forma que o documento que está sendo salvo permanece disponível para o usuário para edição. " - https://httpstatuses.com/204

Answer (score 25, accepted):

O retorno 204 é pura convenção, o código significa uma resposta de sucesso sem nenhum conteúdo (corpo).

A requisição **`OPTIONS`** em si é uma requisição "especial" feita pelo browser quando você requisita recursos de outro domínio (*cross-domain*). Serve para checar se você está apto a fazer esta requisição para um outro domínio.

Ela envia os *headers* `Access-Control-Request-Method`, `Access-Control-Request-Headers` e `Origin`.

Se o servidor aceitar a requisição, o browser vai receber uma resposta contendo o os *headers* (prefixados com `Access-Control-*`) que definem o que está disponível para determinado *endpoint*.

O nome disso é *[preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)*.

[Você pode ver mais detalhes na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

No seu exemplo, está sendo disparada uma requisição com o *header* `Access-Control-Request-Headers` definido como **`Authorization`** e `Access-Control-Request-Method` definido como **`GET`**.

O servidor respondeu dizendo que está tudo certo (204) e que você pode enviar o cabeçalho `Authorization` que ele será aceito e interpretado, além disso, existe o *header* `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` que define que este *endpoint* pode ser chamado por qualquer origem.

Comment: Excelente resposta, caso não tenha o `CORS` configurado o que é retornado?

Comment: @Marconi depende de implementação. Assim como tudo que digo na resposta também depende. A convenção diz o que fazer, não é nenhuma regra. Porém, muito provavelmente (não posso confirmar agora) o retorno será um código 500 com algum header identificando que é uma requisição que viola o a política de cross-domain.

Comment: Acho interessante ter na resposta, assim ficaria mais completa, o que acha?

Comment: @Marconi sim, eu estava tentando editar, mas desisti. Pelo celular é horrível. Quando eu tiver acesso num dispositivo melhor eu edito.